# Error: accepts at most 1 arg(s), received 5 when running docker build in GitLab-CI YAML file

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

i am trying to run a script in one of my jobs of my `gitlab-ci.yml` file as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExYqg.png)

but i am getting this error `Error: accepts at most 1 arg(s), received 5`

i am new to yml syntax and hence not very sure as to why the command reads as 5 args instead of 1. any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If this is a YAML problem, can you [edit] the question to show how this command is written out in `gitlab-ci.yml`?  (The formatting required for a multi-line command can be different.)

Comment: share the job the way u have written in you .gitlab-ci.yml file

Comment: i have attached a screenshot of the build job that i have written in the file @DavidMaze

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  It looks like you edited the question to remove the YAML file; can you re-edit it to put it back, and delete the screenshot link?

Comment: @elizabethlo Hi. Did you manage to fix that error somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might come from the global structure of your gitlab-ci.yml file. You can have a look at the working example from this repository [minimal gitlab-ci example](https://gitlab.com/xolens/ci-test).
You have to pay particular attention to white spaces at the beginning of lines since yml's structure relies on it

```
variables:
  image_name: test-image-name
build:
  image: docker:20.10.16
  stage: build 
  only:
    - main
  services:
    - docker:20.10.16-dind
  script:
    - >
      docker build -t ${image_name}
      --build-arg VCS_REF=${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
      --build-arg VERSION=${version}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}-${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} ./files
```